# enabling SSL when Tomcat is interfaced by Apache web server using mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, cas, mod-jk

I have `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/cas`, where my java app is running.
after interfacing Tomcat and Apache web server(httpd) when I try `http://192.168.0.117/cas` I can see Login page, but when I try `https://192.168.0.117/cas` I got `404 not found` from Apache web server not from Tomcat.


`Not Found

The requested URL /cas was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.0.117 Port 443`



`https://192.168.0.117/` that answered by Apache web server works well.

so I think the problem should solve by configuring Apache web server to forward some request to tomcat.
there is some helps on internet but there isn't a step by step guideline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are using the Apache Tomcat Connector to connect Apache and Tomcat. Try to find the place in Apache where your SSL is configured, for example by a `grep -R SSLEngine *`. Then try to place the lines of the Apache Tomcat Connector configuration file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/jk.load` which are responsible for the connection that should be protected (say `JkMount /idp worker1`) inside the `<VirtualHost>` of the SSL configuration file. For Ubuntu or Debian, this may be the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` file.

Comment: This is a good answer. Moving the JkMount and JkUnmount directives from the mod_jk.conf file to the VirtualHost node in httpd-ssl.conf worked for me.